# initialize derived class from virtual class array

Tags: c++

i have virtual class person from which is derived to 2 classes student and teacher:

guys can someone plz tell me how to initialize p[counter] as teacher or student ??

this is the virtual function

```
class person 
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    virtual void print()=0;
};
```

first derived class teacher

```
class teacher : public person
{
public:

    int salary;
    teacher();
    teacher(int x,string y,int z);
    void print();

};
```

second derived class student

```
class student : public person
{
public:
    char grade;
    double fees;
    student();
    student(string a,int b,char c,double d);
    void print();

};




int main()
{
    cout<<"Insert 's' for student and 't' for teacher"<<endl;

    string S;
    cin>>S;
    person *p;

    here you either enter s for student or t for teacher, and also we create a dynamic array for p as type person


    for(int counter=0;counter<4;counter++)
    {
        if (S=="s" || S=="S")
        {

            string name;
            int age;
            char grade;
            int fees;
            cout<<"Input name,age,grade,fees"<<endl;
            cin>>name;
            cin>>age;
            cin>>grade;
            cin>>fees;
            p[counter]=student(name,age,grade,fees);
        }
```

here above is where the p[counter doesnt work to initializing to student, it gives me an error then says that p isnt initialized in a run time error
i tried adding new but it gave me a compilation error...
            else if (S=="t" || S=="T")
            {

```
            string name2;
            int age2;
            int salary;
            cout<<"Input age,name,salary"<<endl;
            cin>>name2;
            cin>>age2;
            cin>>salary;
            p[counter]=teacher(age2,name2,salary);
        }
```

here we have the same thing for teacher
            else 
            {
                cout<<"error"<

```
        cin>>S;

    }

    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl;


    delete [] p;
    return 0;
}
```

here are the function implementations

```
teacher::teacher()
{
    name="None";
    age=0;
    salary=0;
}
teacher::teacher(int x,string y,int z)
{
    name=y;
    age=x;
    salary=z;
}
void teacher::print()
{
    cout<<"Dr."<<name<<endl
        <<"age:"<<age<<endl
        <<"slary:"<<salary<<"$"<<endl;
}

student::student()
{
    name="None";
    age=0;
    grade='F';
    fees=0;
}
student::student(string a,int b,char c,double d)
{
    name=a;
    age=b;
    grade=c;
    fees=d;
}
void student::print()
{
    cout<<"Student: "<<name<<endl
        <<"Age: "<<age<<endl
        <<"Grade: "<<grade<<endl
        <<"Fees: "<<fees<<" $"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: p is a pointer to a person, not an array of pointers.  An array of 4 pointers would be person *p[4].   You also need the "new" operator to create a student or teacher.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain errors:

`P` is a pointer and you are trying to use it as an array of pointers.

As your `counter` seems to be looping 4 times. So, you can define the `p` as `person *p[4];`
This will create array of pointers of base class person.

Then while assignment `p[counter]=student(name,age,grade,fees);` or `p[counter]=teacher(age2,name2,salary);` you have to use `new` operator. Then it will be

```
p[counter]=new student(name,age,grade,fees);
```

and

```
p[counter]=new teacher(age2,name2,salary);
```